# How to restore system from windows.old manually after Windows10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10

I just upgraded a brand new T100 chi with 32 Gb of disk to Windows 10. The option to restore Windows 8 is not proposed though Windows.old is present.

How can I do so manually ?

Comment: look if this still works: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971760

Comment: Would like to know if this works....I might have to try it...I can see issues with 64bit systems and program files.