# windows.old folder restored from external backup is not recognized for rollback in Windows 10 insider preview

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-10-preview, windows.old

Would like to do a proper rollback with the windows.old folder of Windows 10 which was restored from external backup to it's original location;
yet the system and startup dialog negates the option.

Any registry flags I need to reset?

Comment: Was asked before with same comment but no answer....http://superuser.com/questions/961180/how-to-restore-system-from-windows-old-manually-after-windows10-upgrade?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Evidently Windows 10 deletes the following 2 hidden folders after 30 days, and they are needed to roll it back while in Windows 10. You need more than the windows.old folder

> $Windows.~WS
>
> $Windows.~BT

[Source](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rollback-windows-10-after-30-days)

I am sure there is a manual way to do [as there was with W7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971760), but I have not experimented or found a HowTo article so far.

Comment: I'll try that next

Comment: Basically a roll back is replacing folders and files from the Windows.old folder, then fix the bootloader to work with the old OS.

Comment: So it's impossible to roll back after more than 30 days?

Comment: Who said impossible? Everything is impossible until its not.

Comment: My workaround was simply to restore from an entire backup dated before the upgrade.Ugly but functional.

Comment: @Tetsujin resorted to that as well, just kept the current user profiles.